# How Can I List All Azure Virtual Machines in All Resource Groups

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Using `Azure.ResourceManager.Compute`, how can I list all Virtual Machines in all Resource Groups? I want to avoid iterating through all the resource groups collecting virtual machines from each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just request the VMs in the subscription you are authenticated to
Something like this should work fine.

```
# Import the Azure Resource Manager Compute module
Import-Module -Name Az.Compute

# Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Get all virtual machines across all resource groups in the subscription
$virtualMachines = Get-AzVM 

# Output the virtual machines
$virtualMachines | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a C# answer, but this answer gave me clues on what to look for.

Comment: Sorry , I suppose the namespace should have given it away.  happy that you found the solution to your problem. CU